# Powershell script to update Navigation.GlobalIncludeSubSites not applying change

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following PowerShell script to update the Navigation.GlobalIncludeSubSites value from true to false, which is working, except that the changes are not properly applied.

By that I mean that if I look at the `AreaNavigationSettings.aspx` page for a site before I run the script I see that "Show subsites" is checked (and the page is showing the wrong menu). After I run the script below, and check that page again, the checkbox is unchecked, but the site is still showing the wrong menu. Only after I click OK on the `AreaNavigationSetting.aspx` page does the correct menu show up.

As you can see in my code, I am using `$pubWeb.Update()`, so I'm not sure why the changes aren't being applied without manually clicking OK on each `AreaNavigationSettings.aspx` page, which defeats the purpose of using the script in the first place.

```
function ProcessSubWebs($currentWeb)
{       
   foreach($sub in $currentWeb.Webs)
   {
      if($sub.Webs.Count -ge 0)
      {
         Write-Host -ForegroundColor black $sub.Url
         UpdateNavigation($sub)
         ProcessSubWebs($sub)
         $sub.Update()
         $sub.Dispose()
      }            
   }        
}

function UpdateNavigation($web)
{
    $pubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor green $pubWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludeSubSites
    $pubWeb.Navigation.InheritGlobal = $true
    $pubWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludeSubSites = $false
    $pubWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludePages = $false
    $pubWeb.Update()
}

ProcessSubWebs(Get-SPWeb -identity http://myserver/site1)
Write-Host -ForegroundColor red "FINISHED"
```

Any ideas?

**[update based on Dave Wise's answer below]**

**Replace**

```
$pubWeb.Update()
```

**with**

```
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = 1;
$web.Update()
```

**worked for me! Thanks Dave :)**

Comment: Are you using output caching?

Comment: I don't even know what that is, so I could be without realizing it. I did a quick google on that, and I don't think so. The script shows me that the navigation 'show subsites' option is unchecked, and so does the web page `areanavigationsettings.aspx`, so it's not just powershell reporting cached or old info. The setting is getting changed, but not applied/saved.

Comment: Go to Site Settings -> Site Collection Output Cache and then look for the profile listed for Anonymous and for Authenticated.  If both say "Disabled" then you are not using caching. However, if a profile other than "Disabled" is listed, that would mean that the pages themselves are being cached for a specified amount of time (usually 3 minutes) and that any changes would not appear during that time.

Comment: Thanks for the steps. Both `Anonymous Cache Profile` and `Authenticated Cache Profile` are set to `Disabled`. Your point about 3 minute sis interesting. I contacted the authoring of the article where I got the script (and adapted it), and he said that the updates where a timer job. That said, it's been hours now, and still the sites are not having the 'show subsites' change applied.

Comment: The only other suggestion I have would be to try doing a `$pubWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;` prior to the `.Update()`

Comment: I think that did the trick! I made a subtle change based on trial and error: rather than use `$pubWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;`, I applied that to my $web and changed `true` to `1`, and also did `$web.Update()` instead of `$pubWeb.update()` If you want to repost that last comment as an answer, I will mark it as such, and post my final code for others to use. Cheers, Dave :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing a `.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;` prior to the `.Update()`

Comment: That worked for me, with a subtle change. In my code above, I changed `$pubWeb.Update()` to be 
    $web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = 1;
    $web.Update()

i.e. I did not update $pubWeb, but $web instead, with your suggestion as well.