# Modifying Global Navigation Settings in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I am working on a PowerShell script to provision a site collection with a predefined hierarchy. Since the PowerShell breadth is so limited, most of this is done via functions that are CSOM code.

As part of this, I need to have a unified global navigation. I have been able to enable the publishing feature without problems. My issues arise when I have to step through each site and set the global navigation settings to:

1. Use structural navigation on the Rootweb, including subsites
2. In each subsite, inherit from the parent, and include subsites.

I have seen a lot of this floating around for on-prem like [Powershell script to update Navigation.GlobalIncludeSubSites not applying change](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29449/powershell-script-to-update-navigation-globalincludesubsites-not-applying-change), I need it to work for Office 365. I can't seem to get a right handle on the publishing web and the navigation settings.

Does anyone have a definitive example or a reference to how to modify the current navigation via CSOM in PowerShell for Office 365?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013 was introduced a new [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing(v=office.15).aspx) and [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing.navigation(v=office.15).aspx) namespaces in CSOM API. But unfortunately it is not supported to get/set `Show subsites` & `Show pages` navigation settings using [WebNavigationSettings class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing.navigation.webnavigationsettings(v=office.15).aspx) since those properties are not exposed.

Having said that I propose to utilize [ClientPortalNavigation.cs](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/7090347) which represents a CSOM counterpart for SSOM [PortalNavigation Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.portalnavigation(v=office.14).aspx) which in turn allows to get/set navigation settings including `Show subsites` & `Show pages` navigation settings.

**Implementation**

In order to consume [ClientPortalNavigation.cs](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/7090347) in PowerShell below is demonstrated how to implement it as a custom [PowerShell snap-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.pssnapin(v=vs.85).aspx).

- Build an assembly from [SharePoint.Client.Navigation.PowerShell](https://github.com/vgrem/SharePoint.Client.Navigation.PowerShell)
  project
- Install the specified assembly using [Installer Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95(v=vs.110).aspx):`InstallUtil SharePoint.Client.Navigation.PowerShell.dll`
- Register Windows PowerShell snap-in:`Add-PsSnapin
  SharePoint.Client.Navigation.PowerShell`

**Usage**

The example demonstrates how to set SharePoint Online Global navigation `Show subsites` & `Show pages` settings via CSOM API in PowerShell:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name SharePoint.Client.Navigation.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PsSnapin SharePoint.Client.Navigation.PowerShell
}
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")

Function Get-SPOCredentials([string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
   $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
   return New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
}

$UserName = "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$Url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"
$credentials = Get-SPOCredentials -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
SetGlobalNavigation -Url $Url -Credentials $credentials -IncludePages $true -IncludeSubSites $true
```

**References**

[Access and Manipulate Navigation Settings via SharePoint Client Object Model](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/10/22/access-and-manipulate-navigation-settings-via-sharepoint-client-object-model/)

Comment: I can build it, I just can't seem to get PowerShell to recognize it to try it.

Comment: Probably it could not be recognized by PowerShell since it should be installed using **x64** version of `InstallUtil.exe` ([more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323140/system-badimageformatexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-from-installuti))

Comment: I'll keep trying, would gacutil work too?

Comment: Eric, for some reason i haven't noticed your last comment, `gacutil` should work as well.