# PowerShell CSOM set web inheritance

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, global-navigation

Piggy backing off my last question, [Modifying Global Navigation Settings in SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151167/modifying-global-navigation-settings-in-sharepoint-online), is it possible to set a subsites navigation inheritance to use the same as the parent?

If it is possible via [JSOM](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/03/sharepoint-2013-change-navigation.html), I'm assuming it is possible via CSOM in Powershell or am I mistaken?

I've tried various iterations of this:

```
$Url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/eric/DDD"
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credential.UserName, $credential.Password)

$currentWeb = $context.Web      
$web.Navigation.UseShared = $true
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.navigation.useshared.aspx) property for the Navigation class:

```
public bool UseShared { get; set; }
```

Setting it true should inherit the navigation.  So this should work:

```
$web.Navigation.UseShared = $true;
```

However, it seems it applies to all navigation, top nav *and* quick launch.

Comment: It should, but I can't seem to get it to set. I've tried that before, it doesn't error, but it doesn't set the property either.

Comment: I must have had a typo somewhere or an invalid parameter reference, this  works.